# VBA Pivot Table appear on specific sheet

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

Currently I have this code and it runs smoothly. But, the Pivot created seems did not appear on "ST_TicketPivot" sheet that I created.

So, how can I make the Pivot appear on sheet that I want?

```
Private Sub ST_Tickets()
    Dim objTable As PivotTable, objField As PivotField
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Paste Record").Select
    Range("A1").Select

    Sheets.Add.Name = "ST_TicketsPivot"
    Sheets("ST_TicketsPivot").Activate


    Set objTable = Sheet1.PivotTableWizard
    objTable.PivotCache.MissingItemsLimit = xlmissingItemNone
    objTable.PivotCache.Refresh

    Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("Priority")
    objField.Orientation = xlColumnField

    Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("Status")
    objField.Orientation = xlRowField

    Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("Contact Name") ' change with type
    objField.Orientation = xlRowField

    Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("Salesforce Case Number")
    objField.Orientation = xlDataField
    objField.Function = xlCount

End Sub
```

Comment: You can specify the destination: `Set objTable = Sheet1.PivotTableWizard(TableDestination:=Activesheet.Cells(3, "A")` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the `PivotWizard` create a new sheet to place the Pivot Table, so you'll have to rename it by using `objTable.Parent.Name`.

Give this a try :

```
Private Sub ST_Tickets()
    Dim objTable As PivotTable, objField As PivotField, Ws As Worksheet
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Paste Record").Range("A1").Select

    Set Ws = Sheets.Add
    Ws.Name = "ST_TicketsPivot"

    Set objTable = Sheet1.PivotTableWizard(TableDestination:=Ws.Cells(3, "A"))
    objTable.PivotCache.MissingItemsLimit = xlmissingItemNone
    objTable.PivotCache.Refresh

    Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("Priority")
    objField.Orientation = xlColumnField

    Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("Status")
    objField.Orientation = xlRowField

    Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("Contact Name") ' change with type
    objField.Orientation = xlRowField

    Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("Salesforce Case Number")
    objField.Orientation = xlDataField
    objField.Function = xlCount

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm surprised that it didn't work... I made an edit to include @Rory suggestion, give it a try! ;)

Comment: Finally! Thanks a lot @R3uK ! ><